# PHP Parsing Associative Array

Tags: php, associative-array

I have a quick question that I just can't seem to figure out even though it should be straightforward.

I have an associative array of the following structure:

```
 [uk] => Array
        (
            [TW] => 1588
            [LY] => 12936
            [LW] => 13643
        )
```

I am displaying it in an HTML table as follows.

```
foreach ($leads as $country) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $country . '</td><td>' . $country['TW'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LY'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LW'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

but the country comes out as `Array` so I'm just wondering what I am doing wrong to get the `uk` part out.

**Output**

```
Array   1588    12936   13643
```

Comment: Try this foreach ($leads as $key=>$country) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $country['TW'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LY'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LW'] . '</td></tr>';
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like:

```
foreach ($leads as $name => $country) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $name. '</td><td>' . $country['TW'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LY'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LW'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Now, `$name` in the loop is the key (in this case 'uk') and `$country` is the value of the element, in this case the array `(TW => 1588, LY => 12936, LW => 13643)`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the key of the item you're looping through, you need to use a different `foreach` syntax:

```
foreach($leads as $code=>$country) {
    var_dump($code,$country);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the array key for each $country item. Add it to foreach.

```
foreach ($leads as $key => $country) {
echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $country['TW'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LY'] . '</td><td>' . $country['LW'] . '</td></tr>';
  }
```